# Exporting data to excel sheet in php

Tags: php

For my website  i want to give the user a new opportunity ,which is to export all user details in a excel file.It is possible to perform in php,if possible than may i get a link to this kind of work.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use the built-in fputcsv function

[PHP Manual - fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)